# transfering images into another data directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a data structure format as below:

```
Dataset:
    training-
             -Cat
             -dog
             -monkey
```

I would like to transfer/move 10 percent of files from each dataset to validation dataset. How can I do it using python?. It should automatically create the directories as well

```
Dataset:
    validation-
             -Cat
             -dog
             -monkey
```

Comment: what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import os
source = 'C:/.../training/'
destination = 'C:/.../validation/'
 
if not os.path.exists(destination):
  # Create a new directory because it does not exist 
  os.makedirs(destination)

allfiles = os.listdir(source)
 
for f in allfiles:
    os.rename(source + f, destination + f)
```

Comment: What about only wanting to transfer/move 10 percent of the files?

Comment: YES, I WOULD Like to transfer only 10 percent ? how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should help, yet not tested on Windows (only Ubuntu). But you can modify if path string is different on Windows OS.

Tested on : Python = 3.6.13, numpy = 1.19.2

```
from glob import glob
import os
import numpy as np
import shutil


def copy_folder(src, dst, percent_keep=0.1):
  all_files = glob(f"{src}/*")
  # select folders
  folders = [folder for folder in all_files if os.path.isdir(folder)]
  # select files
  all_files = [file for file in all_files if os.path.isfile(file)]
  print(f"There are {len(folders)} folders in {src.split('training')[-1]}")
  print(f"There are {len(all_files)} files in {src.split('training')[-1]}")
  for folder in folders:
    # iterate through subfolders
    copy_folder(folder, dst, percent_keep)

  if len(all_files) > 0:
    # find path to be attacked to validation path
    remaining_path = src.split("training/")[-1]
    new_path = os.path.join(dst, "validation", remaining_path) # new path for destination
    if not os.path.exists(new_path):
      os.makedirs(new_path)
    # select samples from all files you have
    keep_files = np.random.choice(all_files, int(len(all_files) * percent_keep))
    print(f"Copying {len(keep_files)} random files")
    for index, file in enumerate(keep_files):
      print(f"\rCopying {index+1} / {len(keep_files)}", end="")
      shutil.copyfile(file, os.path.join(new_path, file.rsplit("/")[-1]))
    print("")


if __name__ == "__main__":
  src = "/home/user/Dataset/training" # Should be path to training folder 

  # should be path of directory one below training folder
  # (lets say root) it will attach validation folder later in code
  dst = "/home/user/Dataset/" 
  copy_folder(src, dst, 0.1)
```

if you dont want to use `numpy` for selecting random file to copy to validation folder, use `random` library.

Something like:

```
keep_files = random.choices(all_files,k=int(len(all_files) * percent_keep) )
```

If you dont want to use `shutils` or `glob`, you can use `os` library:

```
os.lisdirs() # instead of glob
os.rename() # instead of shutils (maybe somethind different, not tested)
```

if you dont want random samples , use :

```
keep_files = all_files [:int(len(all_files) * percent_keep)]
```